# RxSwift, count how many equal consecutive Equatable items are emitted

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have an Observable that emits a sequence of Equatable elements.
The stream may contain consecutive sequences of equal elements (for instance in the sequence [1, 1, 1, 18, 2, 2, 0, -1] element 1 is repeated 3 times, 2 is repeated 2 times).
I need to compress the sequence substituting for every distinct element a tuple containing the element and the number of repetitions that were present in the original stream:

```
1, 1, 1, 18, 21, 21, 0, -1, -8, -8, 14, 14, 14...

(1, 3), (18, 1), (21, 2), (0, 1), (-1, 1), (-8, 2), (14, 3)...
```

I managed to count repetitions with the `scan` operator, but it emits all the partial computations that shouldn't be part of the final sequence:

```swift
let numbers = Observable<Int>.from([
    0, 0,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    2,
    0, 0, 0,
    6, 6,
    ])

let reps = numbers
    .scan((0, 0), accumulator: {
        (prev: (Int, Int), new: (Int)) in
        if prev.0 == new {
            return (new, prev.1 + 1)
        } else {
            return (new, 1)
        }
    })

reps.subscribe(onNext: {
        print("\($0)")
    })

// expected:
// (0, 2), (3, 5), (2, 1), (0, 3), (6, 2)
//
// result:
// (0, 1), (0, 2),
// (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5),
// (2, 1),
// (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3),
// (6, 1), (6, 2)
```

Comment: This is called run length encoding, btw.

Comment: Could you provide a sample project/playground that can let potential answerers get started with this? I'd love to take a stab, but I don't have the time to set it up right now.

Comment: I’m not at home right now: I’ll provide you a playground on github as soon as I’ll be back at home. In the meanwhile you could try to use the one provided in this tutorial by Scott Gardner, I think it should do the job as well: https://www.raywenderlich.com/158205/rxswift-transforming-operators

Comment: @Alexander https://github.com/luca-i/RxRunLengthEncoding.git (btw: thank you for your interest!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own operator. Here's an example implementation. I create a new observable, that subscribes to `self`'s events. Anytime `self` has a new element, the `.next` case in the `switch` is hit, which does the run-length booking keeping. Whenever a different element, an error, or a completion are encountered, the grouping is emitted.

```
extension ObservableType where Self.E: Equatable {
    func runLengthEncode() -> Observable<(element: E, count: Int)> {
        var lastGrouping: (element: E, count: Int)? = nil

        return Observable.create { observer in
            return self.subscribe { event in
                switch event {
                case .next(let currentElement):
                    if let currentGrouping = lastGrouping {
                        if currentGrouping.element == currentElement {
                            lastGrouping = (element: currentElement, count: currentGrouping.count + 1)
                        }
                        else { // This run ended, a new element was encountered.
                            lastGrouping = (element: currentElement, count: 1) // start a new grouping
                            observer.on(.next(currentGrouping)) // emit the completed grouping
                        }
                    } else {
                        lastGrouping = (element: currentElement, count: 1)
                    }

                case .error(let error):
                    if let lastGrouping = lastGrouping { observer.on(.next(lastGrouping)) } // Emit the last unemitted grouping.
                    observer.on(.error(error))

                case .completed:
                    if let lastGrouping = lastGrouping { observer.on(.next(lastGrouping)) } // Emit the last unemitted grouping.
                    observer.on(.completed)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also implement a complimentary run length decoding operator:

```
extension ObservableType {
    func runLengthDecode<Element>() -> Observable<Element>
        where Self.E == (element: Element, count: Int) {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            return self.subscribe { event in
                switch event {
                case .next((element: let element, count: let count)):
                    for _ in 1...count {
                        observer.on(.next(element))
                    }


                case .error(let error): observer.on(.error(error))
                case .completed: observer.on(.completed)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test case:

```
let numbers = Observable<Int>.from([
    0, 0,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    2,
    0, 0, 0,
    6, 6,
])

let runLengthEncoded = numbers.runLengthEncode()
runLengthEncoded.subscribe { print($0) }

let runLengthDecoded = runLengthEncoded.runLengthDecode()
runLengthDecoded.subscribe { print($0) }
```

Comment: @Alenxander: Thank you to take the time to answer my question. I thought about write my own rx operator, but I didn't find any tutorial online and looking into the RxSwift repository code didn't help me so much because the code is too complicated for me to be understandable. All I was able to do was wrapping my own solution into an ObservableType extension, which worked, but yours is definitely more elegant and it is for me a great way to learn.

Comment: @Luca I couldn't find anything about it either, it actually took me a surprisingly long time. I don't know if this is the canonical way to make a custom operator, but it seems decent enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think I come up with a possible solution:

1. Create a new Observable of `Optional<T>` (where `T` is the `Equatable` element in `numbers`) taking away the first item from the `numbers` and appending (`concat`) a `nil` element to it.
2. `zip` that Observable with the `reps` Observable already generated.
3. `filter` the resulting Observable.

```
// step 1
let shiftedNumbers = Observable<Int?> = numbers
    .skip(1)
    .map({ $0 })
    .concat(Observable<Int?>.just(nil))

// step 2 and 3
let zippedNumbers = Observable<(Int, Int)?>
    .zip(counts, shortNumbers, resultSelector: {
        if $1 == nil || $1 != $0.0 {
            return $0
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    })
    .filter({
        $0 != nil
    })

zippedNumbers.subscribe(onNext: {
    print($0!)
})

// result:
// (0, 2), (3, 5), (2, 1), (0, 3), (6, 2)
```

Skipping the first element of the `numbers` sequence makes it possible to "see in advance" what the next element will be giving us a chance to emit the right tuple.